# how to handle quote ('') while importing date from external file to sql in python?

Tags: python, dynamic-sql, impala

I have a param.yaml file having content as

```
effective_date_raw_from : '2019-08-30'
effective_date_raw_to : '2019-09-02'
```

but while I am importing it in python script

```
print(" start : " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    with open(r'C:\Users\anil\param.yaml') as file:
        param_list = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        print(param_list)
        print(param_list['effective_date_raw_from'])
        print(param_list['effective_date_raw_to'])
        print(type(param_list['effective_date_raw_from']))
        print(type(param_list['effective_date_raw_to']))

query_template = """
            select *
            from  transaction
            where effective_date between {{effective_date_raw_from}} and {{effective_date_raw_to}} and rnk_domain = 'RAW'
            """
    j = JinjaSql(param_style='pyformat')
    query, bind_params = j.prepare_query(query_template, param_list)
    print(query)
    print(bind_params)
    df_raw = pd.read_sql(query, conn, params=bind_params)
    print(df_raw)
```

I am getting an error i.e.: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (110) Error while
executing a query in Impala: [HY000] : AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 4:\n...re effective_date between %(effective_date_raw_from_1)...\n                             ^\nEncountered: %\nExpected: CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, NOT, NULL, REPLACE, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER\n\nCAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error\n (110) (SQLPrepare)')
because the parameter that

I am importing is having the missing

> `''`

quote(although they are of string type ) hence query is returning error is there any way to handle it..

Comment: I think your file should look like this:

'effective_date_raw_from' : '2019-08-30'
'effective_date_raw_to' : '2019-09-02'

Comment: @TrishantPahwa: YAML doesn't need the quotes.

Comment: It would help if you included the error message (including traceback).

Comment: I gues put the quotes around there like this? `...between "{{effective_date_raw_from}}" and...`

Comment: @Jasmijn  I have added the error message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is in the error message:

> Encountered: %
>
> Expected: CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, NOT, NULL, REPLACE, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER

This means that the SQL engine you're using doesn't support the "pyformat" style of parameters.

You may have more success with:

```
j = JinjaSql(param_style='qmark')
```

or

```
j = JinjaSql(param_style='named')
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you should use the json module to convert the string file

```
import json
file = json.loads(open(r'C:\Users\anil\param.yaml'))
```